# MaterialUI TextField not firing onChange when deleting whole field for first time

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this textField component from Material UI.

```
<TextField
      defaultValue={formObject.stockname}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange({ key: "stockname", value: e.target.value })
/>
```

Problem is, after page refresh, defaultValue is being loaded, if on input field, I'll press CTRL+A and Delete button, it'll delete text, but once I click away, text returns and "formObject" remains unchanged. Meaning onChange does not fire, however, if I do it the second time, it works properly.

What could be the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show `handleChange` implementation, and is `formObject` a state?

Comment: handleChange is just this: `const handleChange = (payload) => {
    dispatch(updateValue(payload));
  }` - I've basically moved it out of onChange={} for testing purposes. For formObject, yes, that is state of redux. I found that changing onChange to onInput - solves my problem, however I'm not sure if there's any downsides to using onInput rather than onChange which seems to be more popular.